# Android bottom sheet toolbar like Telegram

Tags: android, android-toolbar, bottom-sheet

In my android app i have bottom sheet and i tried to make it like app `Telegram` where on bottom sheet appears it has thick border over the image gallery items and when expand to top it shows toolbar with an little animation with spinner and back button.

My layout file of `BottomSheetDialogFragment`

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout

        android:id="@+id/topBarBottomSheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/attachmentOption"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp" />



        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/closeButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_highlight_off_black_36dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp" />

        <SearchView
            android:id="@+id/searchView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/closeButton"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@id/closeButton"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/searchViewEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Name"
            android:layout_below="@id/searchView"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

This is what telegram doing

[image]

That's what i achieve so far

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of RelativeLayout, Use a LinearLayout of width `match_parent` , height `?actionBarSize`, orientation `horizontal` and gravity `center_vertical`. And choose a background as you wish